# Using custom polymer elements in with bower

Tags: polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I've got a custom Polymer element `polymer install element` call it `<x-custom-element>` once created i'm unable to `polymer serve` until I change the links to reference the bower components in the elements folder.

When I publish the element to my git repository I need to change the references in the elements `<links rel="import" href="bower_components/"> to`href="../` or what ever the link is to use the bower_components folder form the directory that install the element.

For example to be able to serve the file via `polymer serve`, with this file structure

- bower.json
- bower_components/
- test/
- temo/
- x-custom-element.html

The links in `x-custom-element.html` need to refer to `/bower_components/*`

But to be able to be usable as a bower import I must change the references to `../*`

Is there anyway to remedy this process? How should you approach this problem.

Create a script to change all the link back and forth?
What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example project directory is missing `index.html` in the root. This should be automatically generated by `polymer-cli` (i.e., `polymer init element`), and it should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>x-foo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iron-component-page src="x-foo.html"></iron-component-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't have any problems viewing the site with `polymer serve -o` after generating the element project with `polymer init element` (`polymer-cli` v0.16.0, `polyserve` v0.13.0, macOS Sierra 10.12).

[image]